# Fetch the record id where timestamp is significantly different from the preceeding row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**Scenario**

You have a table containing records and each record has a field for Unix timestamp. Table structure can be

```
CREATE  TABLE `record` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `timestamp` INT NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 );
```

**Situation:**

Server goes down for any reason and the records are not coming in for lets say 1 hour. End of the day you go and check there are fewer than normal records in the table and you have to check if the records stopped coming in during the day at any time.

**Data:**

```
id  timestamp   
1   1391607328
2   1391607330
3   1391607332
4   1391607334
5   1391607336
6   1391607353
7   1391607355
8   1391607357
9   1391607359
10  1391607361
11  1391607377
12  1391608378
13  1391608379
14  1391608380
15  1391608381
16  1391608382
17  1391608383
18  1391608384
19  1391608385
20  1391608386
```

**Requirement:**

We have to now find out which was the last row which was inserted normally and after that there is a big time gap before the next row is inserted. Let's quantify this time gap to 1000 for this example.
So we check those 20 records and notice that the row we are looking for is `id=12` because that is the row which has a gap of more than 1000 from the timestamp in the previous row.

**Current Solution:**

```
SELECT a.id,a.timestamp 
FROM record a 
WHERE a.timestamp - 1000 >  
   (SELECT MAX(b.timestamp) 
    FROM record b 
    WHERE b.id<a.id
   )
```

**TL;DR: What's the question then?**

This solution works fine for a small table but it is not efficient for a long table scan for obvious reasons, how can this query be improved to obtain the same result efficiently? Please note that the `timestamp` is indexed.

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b66d1/1)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is probably to use variables.  I would be inclined to phrase it this way:

```
select id, timestamp, prev_timestamp
from (SELECT id, timestamp, @prevtimestamp as prev_timestamp,
             @prevtimestamp := timestamp
      FROM record r cross join
           (select @prevtimestamp := -1) as const
      order by id
     ) r
where timestamp - prev_timestamp > 1000;
```

Note:  The `order by` should be a no-op because `id` is a primary key.

EDIT:

If you create an index on `record(timestamp)` the following will also be efficient:

```
select r.*
from record r
where not exists (select 1
                  from records r2
                  where r2.timestamp > r.timestamp - 1000 and
                        r2.timestamp < r.timestamp
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, and yes `timestamp` is indexed

Answer (score 1):

Just fetches you id having the maximum timespan gap! (Assuming `ID` is incremental by 1)

```
SELECT previous AS TIMESTAMP ,previous_id AS id
FROM
(
  SELECT a.id,b.id AS previous_id ,a.TIMESTAMP,b.TIMESTAMP AS previous,(b.TIMESTAMP - a.TIMESTAMP) AS diff
  FROM record a
   INNER JOIN record b
     ON b.id -1 = a.id
  ORDER BY diff DESC
) AS result_table
LIMIT 1
```